# How do I check if a Scala HigherKinded TypeTag is an Array?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to convert a type tag into a java class that maintains/persists normally-erased type parameters. There are quite a few libraries that benefit from conversions like these (such as Jackson, and Guice). I'm currently trying to migrate `Manifest` based code to `TypeTag` since `Manifest`s are insufficient for some corner cases.

The JVM treats Arrays special in comparison to other data types. The difference between a `classOf[Int]` and `classOf[Array[Int]]` is that the method `Class.isArray()` will return true for the latter.

The `Manifest` implementation was simple. `Manifest.erasure` was a `Class` instance where `isArray()` was already valid/true.

The `TypeTag` implementation is trickier. There is no quick and easy `erasure` method. In fact the 'similar' TypeTag variant, `RuntimeMirror.runtimeClass`, prefers not to handle creating any Array based classes on our behalf. Read the documentation:

> Note: If the Scala symbol is ArrayClass, a ClassNotFound exception is
>   thrown because there is no unique Java class corresponding to a Scala
>   generic array

To work around this I try to detect if it is an Array. If it is an array, then I manually create the class object. However, I've come across an additional edge case when Array has an unknown type argument.

First let me show you an example that is not a HigherKinded type.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
class A[T]

val innerType = typeOf[A[Array[_]]].asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args.head
innerType <:< typeOf[Array[_]] // Returns true.
```

So far so good.

```
class B[T[_]]

val innerType = typeOf[B[Array]].asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args.head
innerType <:< typeOf[Array[_]] // Returns false.
```

I can't create a typeOf[Array] since it complains about the missing parameter. How can I detect that B has an type parameter of Array?

Also, what would the class instance look like in this case? Is it an Array[Object]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decompose again:

```
scala> innerType match { case TypeRef(pre, sym, args) => sym == definitions.ArrayClass }
res13: Boolean = true
```

That might get you part-way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to compare typeConstructors:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
class B[T[_]]

val innerType = typeOf[B[Array]].asInstanceOf[TypeRefApi].args.head
innerType.typeConstructor =:= typeOf[Array[_]].typeConstructor
```

```
innerType: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Array
res4: Boolean = true
```

This also works in general when we need to detect the Type is an Array (of any type).

The try to get erased type of such innerType (to compare) fails for Array (while works for others HigherKinded types):

```
class B[T[_]]

val innerType = typeOf[B[Array]].typeArgs.head
innerType.typeArgs
innerType.erasure // fails
innerType.erasure =:= typeOf[Array[_]].erasure
```

```
defined class B

innerType: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Array
res4: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List()
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
  at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:431)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Nil$.head(List.scala:428)
  at scala.reflect.internal.transform.Erasure$ErasureMap.apply(Erasure.scala:126)
  at scala.reflect.internal.transform.Transforms$class.transformedType(Transforms.scala:43)
  at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.transformedType(SymbolTable.scala:16)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeApiImpl.erasure(Types.scala:225)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeApiImpl.erasure(Types.scala:218)
  ... 36 elided
```